# How to invoke a JQuery method after Angular select directive applies a model change?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angularjs-directive, bootstrap-multiselect

I am trying to change the selection of David Stutz's bootstrap-multiselect via Angular `ng-model`:

```
<select ng-model="selection" multiple="multiple" id="my-example">
  <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
  <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
  <option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
  <option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
  <option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
  <option value="onions">Onions</option>
</select>
```

The changes to the model only get applied to the underlying `select` element, but the bootstrap-multiselect doesn't get updated automatically. Looking at its [documentation](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#methods), this is expected: you are required to call `multiselect('refresh')` afterwards to propagate the changes:

```
$('#my-example').multiselect('refresh');
```

My question is:

> How to invoke this method when the model changes after Angular is done updating the `select` element?

Since I need to access the element, I assume directives are the way to go. I was looking at [decorators](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/decorators), which in theory I could use to modify the behavior of the built-in select directive, but I don't know how to get my code invoked at the right moment.

I've prepared a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/Qel04TwXYlWQNyE4Japu) to demo the issue:

- I have two multiselects bound to the same model: a bootstrap-multiselect and a plain one
- I initialize both with a default selection
- The first button changes the selection. The plain multiselect is updated immediatelly, but the bootstrap-multiselect appears unchanged.
- The second button shows the current model value in an alert.
- The third button calls `refresh` on bootstrap-multiselect, which causes it to update. This is what I would like to get called automatically by Angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I managed to solve my problem with a decorator. I based it on the *Directive Decorator Example* in [AngularJS documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/decorators).

Unlike `ngHrefDirective` from the example, [`selectDirective`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.5.x/src/ng/directive/select.js) defines both `preLink` and `postLink`, therefore the `compile` override must also return both. I only needed to change `postLink` though, where `$render` is defined. In my version of the method I simply invoked the original method, which updates the `select` element, and called `multiselect('refresh')` afterwards, which was my original requirement:

```
app.config(['$provide', function($provide) {
  $provide.decorator('selectDirective', ['$delegate', function($delegate) {
    var directive = $delegate[0];

    directive.compile = function() {

      function post(scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {
        directive.link.post.apply(this, arguments);

        var ngModelController = ctrls[1];
        if (ngModelController) {
          originalRender = ngModelController.$render;
          ngModelController.$render = function() {
            originalRender();
            element.multiselect('refresh');
          };
        }
      }

      return {
        pre: directive.link.pre,
        post: post
      };
    };

    return $delegate;
  }]);
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you should mix that (why refresh data with jquery while the data is in angular's watch cycle?). You can do something like this with your options:

```
<option ng-value="Cheese.val">{{Cheese.text}}</option>
<option ng-value="Tomatoes.val">{{Tomatoes.text}}</option>
```

And handle the rest with Angular (maybe google for angular + multiselect)

Comment: I've looked at other Bootstrap multiselect controls that were made for Angular and none have a comparable feature set to [David Stutz's one](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect). The closest one was [Dotan Simha's](https://github.com/dotansimha/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect), but even that one lacks support for clickable option groups, for example. Also, I can have the options hard-coded in the page, I only need to bind the selection.